# How to trigger VB function from onClick()

Tags: vb.net

Am displaying list of available documents in the data grid which are retrieved from the database. Once we click on a specific one then it will retrieve PDF document from the server and display it in the browser.

Currently, if I click a document from the list in the datagrid then it will display the PDF file in a new browser. Here is the code for that :

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("DOC") = "<font color=blue onmouseover=""this.style.cursor='hand';"" title=""Click for PDF"" " + _
             "onclick=""location.replace('index.aspx?Name=" & link & "')"">" & docNum & "</font>"
```

However, now once I click the document then it should trigger a new VB Function by forwarding the document number as the parameter to that function.

I don't know, how to trigger VB Function once we click on a specific document from the data grid. It's not click onClick event for a button because it shows list of available documents.Am working in VB.Net 1.1 so it doesn't have option to use Command Name, Row Command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time since I have done asp.net 1.1 but this documentation says you should still have Command Name:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcommand(v=vs.71)

Comment: I need to use ItemCommand option I guess. However, can you please provide me an example which shows onClick event on any Bound Column field. I need to call VB Function as soon as we click one of the column